# nacl: readdir on an httpfs mount returns an empty folder

Tags: google-nativeclient

I modified `nacl_sdk/pepper_49/examples/demo/flock/flock.cc` with the following change:

```
...
// Mount the images directory as an HTTP resource.
mount("images", "/images", "httpfs", 0, "");



// NEW CODE HERE  
DIR *dir = opendir("/images");
struct dirent *entry;
while((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
{
  fprintf(stdout, "Found '%s'\n", entry->d_name);
}
closedir(dir);



FILE* fp = fopen("/images/flock_green.raw", "rb");
...
```

but I am only getting this

```
Found '.'
Found '..'
```

opening the file `/images/flock_green.raw` using `fopen` works fine. I just cannot see it with `readdir`. Is there a way to get `readdir` to work in NACL? or is it some kind of sandbox restriction?